# Creating a 3d paint streak effect in Blender 2.8

Tags: node-editor, color

First off, I'm quite new to Blender so I appreciate any and all help. I'm trying to make a 3D paint stroke effect like the one below but I've run into some problems.

[image: 3D paint effect]

The method this designer (Pawel Nolbert for reference) uses is actually painting on to transparent film, then photographing the twisted film to achieve this result. In Blender, I tried creating a paint streak then mapping it to a bezier curve to create a similar effect.

[image: Paint Streak]
[image: Node Setup]

I hope this method will work well enough for what I'm trying to do, but I can't figure out my node setup to procedurally generate the multi-colored streaks across the brush stroke. My questions are 1) what's the best way to set up the nodes so the colors can be changed on the fly and 2) is there a better way to achieve this result altogether?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way would be to create a texture, sculpting it is not the way to go in my opinion. I've actually done similar things in C4D. We would shoot real paint on camera on a white background, get rid of the background in photoshop and just assign it to a plane. Then you can do whatever you want with the plane, twist it and move it around. It's the easiest way and give the best result, you can just change color with a HUE node. Use the image to add displacement as well. An other way would be to create the texture fully procedurally but that's a bigger subject.

Give me 10 minutes I'll update my answer with an example .blend file.

EDIT:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I think you're right about just mapping the image texture to a plane. That sounds like an easier method.